# Going over direct manager to CEO about severe conditions

Tags: work-time, escalation

I am currently an employee at a business consulting company. We have several branches and I am a part of a branch in the middle east as a principal consultant.   However my direct management is a part of a different office which is also in the middle east.

We have been facing several issues as a team which we talked about together, with three of our direct managers (the management is a bit haphazard and lacking in clear hierarchy).

The main problems we faced, among others, were unkept promises, continuous tight deadlines, being under-staffed, being forced to work unpaid overtime (with working overtime being considered standard operating procedure), lack of recognition, lack of clear assignment, heavy travel rates for long periods, no clear company structure and lack of policy.

We don't really know who to escalate to, since we have no HR department, with HR issues handled by the same three direct managers.

The team is now at a point of breaking and as a last resort they're prepared to send a collective email to the CEO and the second in command, both in different offices. This could lead to the worst of scenarios, but we don't see any other resolution. Would this be a good solution or are there other ways to address it?  Will this be seen as mutiny? Also what would be the best approach for this with all parties at different offices?

Comment: "Will that be seen as mutiny?"  Depends on what the people in your workplace want to see it as.  I can't speak for what your manager or CEO might do.

Comment: Can you explain why you are not actively looking for a new job?

Comment: If your entire team is willing to quit, the result of sending this message is unlikely to be worse than the result of not sending the message. (Also, I'm not sure if it was a good idea to post this under what I'm assuming is your real name.)

Comment: @Mawg, I don't know why OP isn't but the things he mentions aren't exceptional at all and the probability he will find the same conditions in a new company is high.

Comment: For what it's worth, HR would not have been likely to handle such issues, unless some laws were being broken. [What does HR do for me?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/81773)

Comment: I'm actually currently looking as a result of such conditions. So it seems that's the best solution for all parties rather than going through all the hassle if it's unlikely to reward any results.

Answer (score -1):

> what would be the best approach for this with all parties at different offices?

Search for a new job if you cannot handle the pressure. Right now your managers are doing well getting so much work out of you guys and saving the company money.

Going over three different managers heads is unlikely to end well and you may well find yourself searching for a new job unprepared. In these sorts of situation I don't worry about the rest of the team, my focus would be on my own career and getting out as quietly as I could with a glowing reference rather than pretending I'm a union rep who actually has the leverage to do something.