# What does "HR is not your friend" mean?

Tags: human-resources

[We often get "HR is not your friend" at Workplace.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22HR+is+not+your+friend%22) What does this phrase mean? What are the motivations and incentives of Human Resources (HR) that might set it at odds with an employee?

*I think a canonical answer here would be useful, especially for new entrants into the workforce, and for anyone unfamiliar with the phrase and coming across it here.*

Comment: vtc "HR is not your friend" is an opinion, and is in any event varying by company/country/industry. some HR people & departments - especially government - will be dedicated & legally obligated to helping you. others less so. Uber has seen big problems with their HR department recently, for example.

Comment: I was aware that this question might be perceived as subjective. This is why I specifically asked about the *motivations and incentives* that HR face which might be at odds with the employees', I don't think this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Stephen it is too broad - you're claiming HR in Sweden govt agencies is against you? Or HR in a mining company in the US is against you? You're propagating mistrust *where it isn't necessarily true*

Comment: @bharal: I am not claiming that HR is "against" anyone. There is a difference between someone being my friend, that someone working against me, and that someone working for a third party whose incentives might or might not align with doing what's best for me. I am looking for a discussion of how the motivation of HR differs from a naive perception that HR might, indeed, be our friend. Nor is it my aim to propagate mistrust.

Comment: @Stephen but "discussion" is out of the scope of this site.this is a reddit/quora discussion - i'm not opposed to it, but we're going to end up with a categorical answer screaming "HR are similar to satan" - see the link in Drakemor, where *someone would rather go to trial than have a conversation with HR*

Comment: Again, I am not looking for a discussion. I am looking for someone to explain the motivations that HR works under. I believe understanding HR's point of view would be useful, and there is no discussion about this necessary. I can't help it if a different thread is not helpful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per [great answer of BoboDarph](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/116375/69194)

> That dept. is not there to give you justice. They just do whatever's best for the company, even if that's not right for you individually, even if it's slightly illegal, even if they have to cover stuff up (their asses included). As long as management is happy, HR is also happy.

(...)

> Companies are not court houses, they do not dispense justice, most of them are led by people who only care about the bottom line for their investors. HR is there to help optimize the costs by ensuring employee compliance to internal rules and legal requirements, not to settle disputes between co-workers. They do that only to prevent legal action by employees or the state, and usually are pretty ruthless in defending the company when such possibility arises.

Comment: Actually, that thread is pretty much a duplicate. I'll suggest closing this one as a dupe. Thanks!

Comment: If HR is not your friend, who is? If you're a union member, I suppose they should be, but what about non-union employees?

Comment: @Barmar Unions CAN be, but not always. The law CAN be. Your lawyers are.

Comment: @Barmar: your friends are your friends. Your family *may* be your friends. Some of your coworkers *may* be your friends.

Comment: @StephanKolassa "friend" is being used metaphorically to mean someone who is expected to act on your side in the case of a conflict. So if you don't have a union rep, the implication is that you're on your own -- you have no friends in company management.

Comment: @Barmar: that is correct. You may have *allies*, which is something different. A manager that understands you hold key expert knowledge, which the manager needs to achieve his targets, may well be an ally.

Comment: @StephanKolassa "may" is the key word there. There's no one whose job is to be your ally, in the way that HR's job is to be the company's ally.